# String vs Hash for string type? Hash will have only one key instead of many

Tags: redis

For example, I see many people are doing something like the following:

```
> set data:1000 "some string 1"
> set data:1001 "some string 2"
```

But what about using a hash to minimize the number of keys?

```
> hset data 1000 "some string 1"
> hset data 1001 "some string 2"
```

In the second way, it will only create one `data` key instead of creating many keys in the first way.

Which way is recommended?

I just see some people and tutorial are doing `hset data:10 01 xxx`. This is actually not related to my question. My question is simply asking what it's recommended between `set data:1001 xxx` and `hset data 1001 xxx`.

And I don't plan to modify `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and `hash-max-zipmap-value`. That means the hash will exceed the two values eventually. In such a config, are the two ways the same? or Which way is recommended?

Comment: This question is too broad, but [this memory optimization document](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) should help.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks for your comment. I don't understand why you said the question was too broad. Just storing a simple string, is that broad? Everyone will need to store some strings with unique ids in the key. I am just wondering if I should use a hash or a string type. That's all. Because from my point of view, hash is much better. Only one key is required. But instead of hash, I see many people using string, which I don't understand why and wondering if this matters or just user's preference. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Reasons to use strings:

- you need per value timeouts
- the values are semantically isolated
- you're on cluster and want the values to be sharded over different nodes to spread load (sharding is based on the key)

Reasons to use hashes:

- you want to be able to purge all of them at once (`del`/`unlink`), or have a timeout that impacts *all* of those values at once
- you want to be able to enumerate them (prefer `hscan`/`hgetall` over `scan`/`keys`)
- slightly better memory usage on the keys themselves
- the values are semantically related
- it is OK for all the values to be on the same node (whether single-server or cluster)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am more clear now. I don't use cluster for now, but I will definitely need to configure it in the future when the db gets bigger and bigger. That means I should choose strings instead of hashes then. *(unless I want to do pre-sharding like this `HSET object:12 34 somevalue`, which I really don't bother to do it)* Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on the tradeoffs you want to support. In general, using hashes will have a smaller memory footprint than using simple keys. In fact, it is about an order of magnitude less memory. And access to hash values is constant time. So, if you are using redis simply as a key-value store, then hashes are way more efficient than simple keys.

However, you will want to use simple keys if you need to support expiration, keyspace notifications, etc, then you will need to use simple keys.

Just be careful to tweak the values for `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and `hash-max-zipmap-value` in your redis.conf in order to ensure that hashes are treated correctly for your environment.

You can read all about the details in the [memory optimization section of the documentation](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#use-hashes-when-possible).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I don't need expiration, keyspace notification, and don't modify `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and `hash-max-zipmap-value` (that means the hash will exceed these two values), which way is recommended? OR are the two ways the same? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "which way is recommended". If you don't need any of the special things that simple values give you (expiration, etc) then you should use hashes. You should also tweak your `hash-max-*` values so they are appropriate for your system. It's best to do some experementation and benchmarking to find out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Regarding Marc's answer, I have to use strings instead of hashes if I use cluster and want to shard over different nodes. Due to this limitation, I think I will choose strings instead.